# how can i Manage multiple Linux Users on 1 Amazon EC2 Instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

In my organization of say 5, some times i need to give many people access to the same EC2 Instance. Sharing the private key and the password b/w 5 users is definitely not a good idea!(Also i don't want to share the original pem/ppk file)

So, how can i fix this problem?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Guys Here is my steps what i did in my server

Step 0. Login by default user, “ec2-user”:

```
krishna@hostname:~/mykeys$ ssh -i my_key.pem ec2-user@111.111.11.111
```

Step 1. Create a new user, we will call our new user “krishna”

```
[ec2-user@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ sudo adduser krishna
```

Set password for “krishna” by:

```
[ec2-user@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ sudo su
[root@ip-11-111-111-111 ec2-user]$ passwd krishna
```

Add “krishna” to sudoer’s list by: if you want to give sudo access to krishna

```
[root@ip-11-111-111-111 ec2-user]$ visudo
```

and add this to the last line:

```
krishna ALL = (ALL)    ALL
```

Alright! We have our new user created, now you need to generate the key file which will be needed to login, like we have my_key.pem in Step 0.

Now, exit and go back to ec2-user, out of root.

Step 2. Creating the public and private keys:

```
[ec2-user@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ su krishna
```

Enter the password you created for “krishna” in Step 1.

```
[krishna@ip-11-111-111-111 ec2-user]$ cd /home/krishna/
[krishna@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f krishna-t dsa
[krishna@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ mkdir .ssh
[krishna@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ chmod 700 .ssh
[krishna@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ cat krishna.pub > .ssh/authorized_keys
[krishna@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
[krishna@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ sudo chown krishna:ec2-user .ssh
```

In the above step, krishna is the user we created and ec2-user is the default user group.

```
[krishna@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ sudo chown krishna:ec2-user .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Step 3. Now you just need to download the key called “krishna”
I use scp to download/upload files from EC2, here is how you can do it:

You will still need to copy the file using ec2-user, since you only have the key for that user name. So, you will need to move the key to ec2-user folder and chmod it to 777.

```
[krishna@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ sudo cp krishna/home/ec2-user/
[krishna@ip-11-111-111-111 ~]$ sudo chmod 777 /home/ec2-user/krishna
```

Now come to local machine’s terminal, where you have my_key.pem file and do this: download the key of krishna to local machine then change the mod to 600 by

```
krishna@hostname:~/mykeys$ sudo chmod 600 krishna
```

now its time to take remote of that server

```
krishna@hostname:~/mykeys$ ssh -i krishna krishna@111.111.11.111
```

Thanks
Krishna

Answer (score 2):

"PACS" Puppet, Ansible, Chef, Saltstack.

I strongly suggest using [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html) as it has a user module built right into it, and you can get [up and running](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html) super quickly!

Answer (score 0):

You can just create multiple users on Linux (http://www.tecmint.com/add-users-in-linux/). After that you can for example add a SSH key for each user in /home/USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys. If they need root rights, you can add them to the sudo group. If you need more specific rights, you could implement solutions like LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

First generate a public/private key pair for every user. (In case they don't have one yet)

Then you can put each user public key into $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys on your EC2 instance.